# Need to perform Flux Authentication with react navigator, but I need to be authorized only for some screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator, react-navigation-drawer

```
expo: ^32.0.0
react: 16.5.0
react-navigation: ^3.11.0
```

Hi! When I start my app I need to go to Home without auth. After that I have a DrawerNavigator which dispatches dispatch the following screens:

- Account (need auth)
- Shops (need auth)

#### CONTEXT OF MY NAVIGATION:

I use createDrawerNavigator as main Navigation to dispatch :

```
Home (don't need auth) => call Home screen
Account (need auth) => call SwitchNavigator with Params
Shops (need auth) => call SwitchNavigator with Params
```

#### code:

```
  {
    Home: { screen: Home },
    Account: AppAccessSwitchNavigator('Account'),
    Shops: AppAccessSwitchNavigator('Shops')
  },
  {
    contentComponent: Menu,
    drawerBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
    drawerType: 'front'
  }
));
```

When I go to Account or Shops SwitchNavigator call a AuthLoading screen as this doc `https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/authflow.html`

And my AuthLoading take a params from Drawer to dispatch if I'm auth to the good screen or to the Auth Stack

```
const AppAccessSwitchNavigator = (route) => createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: {
      screen: (props) => <Loading {...props} route={route} />,
    },
    // AuthLoading: Loading,
    Account: Account,
    EditAccount: EditAccount,
    Shops: Shops, 
    EditShop: EditShop,
    SignUp: SignUp,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
)

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ 
    SignIn: SignIn,
    SignUp: SignUp
});
```

---

#### Let's try to login and logout:

That works if I'm not auth I go to signIn screen and back to my initial target screen (Shops for exemple) so my switchNavigator is now Mount, great !

Now logout always in my Shop screen it's ok I'm redirect to SignIn screen BUT if I go to Account screen I'm still login because my stack is always Mount so I didn't pass to my initalRoute (AuthLoading) to check if I'am auth or no. So I have to logout also in my Account Screen !

And the problem is the same with other way :
Now I'm logout in Shops screen and Account screen.
If I login in Shops screen ok I go into Shops screen but now if I go to Account screen I'm stilling in my SignIn screen.

---

#### My AuthLoading file :

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._bootstrapAsync();
  }



  // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
  _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
    // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
    // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? this.props.route : 'Auth');
  };

  // Render any loading content that you like here
  render() {
    console.log("LOADING ")
    return (
      <>
        <NavigationEvents
          onWillFocus={() => this._bootstrapAsync() }
        />
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
          <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

#### My router file :

```
  SignIn: SignIn,
  SignUp: SignUp
});


const AppAccessSwitchNavigator = (route) => createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: {
      screen: (props) => <Loading {...props} route={route} />,
    },
    // AuthLoading: Loading,
    Account: Account,
    EditAccount: EditAccount,
    Shops: Shops, 
    EditShop: EditShop,
    SignUp: SignUp,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
)


const NavigationRoot = createAppContainer(createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Home },
    Account: AppAccessSwitchNavigator('Account'),
    Shops: AppAccessSwitchNavigator('Shops')
  },
  {
    contentComponent: Menu,
    drawerBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
    drawerType: 'front'
  }
));
```